# Docker quick start terminal is not running while installing it shows success message of installation

Tags: docker

i installed docker toolbox in Windows 10 pro and when i start the quick start terminal, the error occurs. i already enabled the virtualization and rechecked multiple times also in BIOS. i gone through various sites for solution but haven't found yet.

i also installed Boot 2 docker in Virtual box. even though any command is not running. when i check the version it displays correctly.

[image]

Comment: Please add errors as text, not images. And when taking images, please take screenshots and don't use a camera.